# Save jupyter cell computation work and load from where I left

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am currently reading the book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques to Build Intelligent Systems" and I am experimenting with some housing analysis example.

My question is: every time I open Jupyter Notebook I have to run all the cells from the beginning one by one in order to continue with my work. I am new to Jupyter and I didn't find any solution to this.
I have imported packages like pandas, a function that downloads tar files and extracts them, also another one loading the data and many others.

Is there any way to safe and load everything (packages, functions, etc) so I can continue my work from the last checkpoint?
I have tried the kernel-restart & run all but is not working
Also, I have tried the cell-Run all but is not working either

I am using Jupyter 6.1.4 installed through anaconda latest version
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: "kernel-restart & run all" is indeed one of the ways to execute all the cells of a notebook. What's the issue with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pickle and store the variables in the computer (disk). Next time you can just unpickle that and get going.

I am assuming you do not want to perform operations repeatedly on some data each time you work on a notebook

```
# For storing 
import pickle
with open('pickle_file_name.pkl','w') as file_object: 
    pickle.dump(<your_data_variable>, file_object)  
  
# For loading 
with open('pickle_file_name.pkl','r') as file_object:
    your_data_variable= pickle.load(file_object)
```

`

Comment: Thank you. So a good practice is to save my data-structures, train_set, test_set, etc as a pickle file once I create them and then move on?

Comment: It's a good practice.. provided it takes a lot of time(you are working on large data). Also more than train test split, the transformation you make on that data is time consuming. So you can save those.

Comment: Also feel free to mark as answered if this answers your question